# Rails 3 Ajax Why does adding params to a get request cause a redirect to the action's path

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters

In my routes.rb file, I have `match ':controller/:action'` at the bottom.

I have a controller called `scheduler` with an action called `seed`.

When I send a GET request to the server based on the following haml, there is no redirect and I can handle the returned data with a jQuery event listener on `ajax:success`, because rails does not redirect me to `scheduler/seed` (the request is sent from `/scheduler`).

```
%a#seeder.btn.btn-primary{:href => 'scheduler/seed', :data => { :remote => 'true', :type => 'html', :method => 'GET'}} Add Timeslots to Selected Day
```

However, as soon as I add `data-params` to the request, whether through the `data-params` field on the html for the anchor tag, or with the following javascript, rails redirects me to `/scheduler/seed` upon receiving the request.

The js:

```
$('#seeder').on('ajax:before', function() {
      $(this).data('params', { date: $('#input_date').value() });
});
```

This is a problem, because I want to stay on `/scheduler/` to update the page based on returned json/xml/etc.